# How to filter product collection using category id in flat mode

Tags: magento-1.9, category, filter, flat-catalog

I have flat mode enabled and I need to filter the product collection using category id, but I am not able to. Here below is my code...

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
                ->addFieldToFilter('category_id', $brandValue['category'])
                ->addFieldToFilter('brands', $brandValue['brand']);
```

But, this is not filtering on the basis of the category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Below code solve your concern

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->load($categoryId)
                    ->getProductCollection();
```

After that you can put your filters and all which attribute to load and all

Comment: I have flat mode enabled and it is not working

Comment: Print Query Using ` echo $collection->getSelect()  ` and check which query comes up

Comment: But, I'm getting only 6 entity_id, in the whole product collection of the category after I use something like:

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->load($categoryId)
                    ->getProductCollection();

        foreach($products->getData() as $product) {
            Mage::log($product['entity_id'], null, 'productId.log');
        }

Comment: reindex And try again

Comment: Done that already.

Comment: Can you give me printed Query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44231/discussion-between-abhishek-dhanraj-shahdeo-and-murtuza).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you an get category's product collection as follows -

```
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($brandValue['category']); // this is category id
$collection = $category->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
;
```

Comment: I have flat mode enabled and it is not working

Answer (score 2):

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $catId))
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->load();
```

In `$catId` pass the array of category ids which you want to filter.

Comment: I have flat mode enabled and it is not working

Comment: yes.. this will work if EAV mode is enabled else you will receive 'Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat::getEntityTablePrefix()' exception